# Splitting routers in backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to develop a backbone.js app in a modular fashion using require.js
I want separate router for each module and so want something like "baseURL" in the router:

```
var Router=Backbone.Router.extend({
 baseUrl:'user',
 routes:{

      "":"loaduserProfile", // should open at url
      "search":"searchUsers", // should open at url + baseUrl

},
```

For this I am thinking of extending the backbone.prototype.route using some custom inclusions like:

```
 route: function(route, name, callback) {
      //CUSTOM CODE
      route = this.baseUrl + route; 

      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
      if (_.isFunction(name)) {
        callback = name;
        name = '';
      }
      if (!callback) callback = this[name];
      var router = this;
      Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
        var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);
        callback && callback.apply(router, args);
        router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
        router.trigger('route', name, args);
        Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
      });
      return this;
    }
```

Is it the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use [Backbone.RouteManager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.routemanager) for you in this situation.

For example:

```
// SubRouter.js
define(function ( require ) {
    return Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "": "index",
            "test": "test"
        },

        index: function() {
            window.alert("SubRouter navigated successfully");
        },

        test: function() {
            window.alert("sub/test triggered correctly");
        }
    });
});

// MainRouter.js
define(function ( require ) {
    var SubRouter = require( 'path/to/SubRouter' );
    return Backbone.RouteManager.extend({
        routes: {
            // Define a root level route
            "": "index",

            // Define a sub route
            "sub/": SubRouter
        },

        index: function() {
            window.alert("MasterRouter navigated successfully");
        }
    });
});

require(['path/to/MainRouter'], function (AppRouter) {
    // Create a new instance of the app router
    app.router = new AppRouter();

    // Trigger the test route under sub
    app.router.navigate("sub/test", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://gist.github.com/tbranyen/1235317 .
I use something like that as a subrouting system thingy for module, where each module is basically a functionality of the application that can be plugged in or out.